# Tracking a 2 dimensional sprite in Java

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm kind of new to this whole thing but I'll get started by asking my first question ever.

So a friend and I are working on a project in which we need to track the player character's head movement and attach items to it. Now is this something that needs to be done in Java or would this be something that would be done in Unity?

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I've never really worked on a project of my own volition before.

Thanks,
BadAssWalrus

Comment: you **can not** now (2016) use "unityscript" in Unity - it is deprecated and does not work.  Enjoy yourself with Unity but use ordinary c#.

Comment: simply learn about "LookAt" command in Unity to do what you say.  But you have lots to learn, enjoy!  the Unity tutorials are excellent, start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so first things first. There is no java in unity, you can do scripting in C#, UnityScript (essentially JavaScript) or Boo.
Now to answer your question, according to my understanding you want to move some objects as the head of the character moves. Now depending upon how you are really trying to move the objects you could either do it with scripting or simply by making the object you are trying to move a child of the head of the character.
Unity has excellent documentation about the scripting API and a lot of tutorials. I suggest you get started by looking at one of these tutorials, and you should get an idea of how things work pretty soon and then you should be able to do pretty much anything you want to do with relative ease.